# PowerQuery XML data import - combine nested table columns into one cell

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need the last 2 columns containing tables to be combined into a cell, currently the format of the import is:
title, link, description, pubDate, guid, toExpand
str, str, str, str, Table, Table

and I need
str, str, str, str, [str, str,..], [str, str, ..]

thanks in advance!

Query:

```
let
    Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/92ec30a9-24ed-4383-b1aa-7b76748f6266/rss.xml")),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Attribute:version", Int64.Type}}),
    channel = #"Changed Type"{0}[channel],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(channel,{{"title", type text}, {"link", type text}, {"description", type text}, {"language", type text}, {"pubDate", type datetime}, {"lastBuildDate", type datetime}}),
    item = #"Changed Type1"{0}[item],
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(item,{{"title", type text}, {"link", type text}, {"description", type text}, {"pubDate", type datetime}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

I tried expanding the tables but that returns just each row as a table

Comment: Your provided code merely returns an error message (Error 500) so cannot be used to reproduce your situation. Please provide sufficient details so others can reproduce your problem and perhaps help you in solving it.

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld, that is weird, it works in MS Excel for me, on different PCs, the connection is open, no auth required.

Comment: Hmmm. Today that web site seems to be working. Wasn't last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expanding those tables won't work. You've got to "tease out" the relevant elements, and then combine them into a text string.

Perhaps something like this:

*Note that I separated items with a semicolon `;` but you might want to use a `linefeed` if you want the results to wrap in end result table*

```
let
    Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/92ec30a9-24ed-4383-b1aa-7b76748f6266/rss.xml")),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Attribute:version", Int64.Type}}),
    channel = #"Changed Type"{0}[channel],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(channel,{{"title", type text}, {"link", type text}, {"description", type text}, {"language", type text}, {"pubDate", type datetime}, {"lastBuildDate", type datetime}}),
    item = #"Changed Type1"{0}[item],
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(item,{{"title", type text}, {"link", type text}, {"description", type text}, {"pubDate", type datetime}}),

//assuming only a single GUID in the "Table"
//If there might be more than one, need some code changes
    #"Expand GUID" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type2",{
        {"guid", each _[#"Element:Text"]{0}}}),
    
//Extract Creator
    Creator = Table.AddColumn(#"Expand GUID", "Creator", each let 
            #"Creator" = try Table.Column([#"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"],"creator"){0} otherwise null ,

        //expand if table
            #"Is Table" = Value.Is(#"Creator",type table),
            Result = if #"Is Table" then Text.Combine(#"Creator"[#"Element:Text"],"; ")
                        else #"Creator"
        in Result, type text),
    Contributor = Table.AddColumn(Creator, "Contributor", each let 
            #"Contributor" = try Table.Column([#"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"],"contributor"){0} otherwise null ,

        //expand if table
            #"Is Table" = Value.Is(#"Contributor",type table),
            Result = if #"Is Table" then Text.Combine(#"Contributor"[#"Element:Text"],"; ")
                        else #"Contributor"
        in Result),
    Identifier = Table.AddColumn(Contributor, "Identifier", each let 
            #"Identifier" = try Table.Column([#"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"],"identifier"){0} otherwise null ,

        //expand if table
            #"Is Table" = Value.Is(#"Identifier",type table),
            Result = if #"Is Table" then Text.Combine(#"Identifier"[#"Element:Text"],"; ")
                        else #"Identifier"
        in Result, type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Identifier,{"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***Last Columns***
[image]